# PrimeNg inline table editing cell width issue

Tags: angular, primeng, inline, edit

Is there a way to prevent PrimeNg table  to expand when using inline-editing feature while keep auto lay out feature enabled?
The example in the docs has the same behavior that I want to disable

StackBlitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo

I tried checking CSS, or the `pEditableColumn` directive if any possible inputs can disable this behavior without any luck.